# Upload video in YouTube - What are the steps

Tags: ios4

In my iOS application I have to upload video to YouTube. So basically I don't know how it is done. So please let me know how I can implement this concept in my application.

Comment: Please refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573418/video-file-share-with-youtube-and-twitter-on-ios-6-and-above)

Answer (score 0):

Open the video you need to upload in youtube via photo gallery. From there you can easily upload it into youtube by clicking on the default upload button in iPhone . Please take a look at that. Thanks