# Video file share with YouTube and Twitter on iOS 6 and above

Tags: ios, video, twitter, upload, youtube-api

I'm working on a Video recording iOS app and as a final step I need to allow the user to share the video file ( MOV ) with FB, Twitter and YouTube. FB implementation is done. But I'm having difficulty with YouTube and Twitter.

I know that Twitter doesn't have Video share option by default and we have to relay on 3rd part services like Vine or twitpic. So I'm ok to drop Twitter video sharing if its too difficult.

But There should be a easy way with YouTube. I have read http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/ but its seems bit outdated.

So I need any one of your's help on this point. Has anyone done any similar implementation for iOS 6+ ? If so kindly give me a helping hand. Or at least a suggestion to use YouTube API with iOS app.

Really appreciate any help.

Kind Regards
Viraj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for answering and comment on this question because that leads me to get the best solution for my problem. Since I was looking for a very simple solution for my problem there was no direct answer to my question.

After searching on Google and trying out possible solutions I think I have found the simplest way of doing this. The resources are

1. https://github.com/stuffmc/YouTubeSample_iOS
2. http://hoishing.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/gdata-objective-c-client-setup-in-xcode-4/

Again the code is bit out dated but still work.

Combination of these two and some changed to the Github code to make it ARC enabled I managed to do it.
Its 2 simple files and GData static library.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: This is using v2 GData API which will be deprecated really soon. I suggest you to go on with Data API v3 as in my examples.

Answer (score 1):

I recently open sourced [YouTube Direct Lite for iOS](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-iOS).

[Here's the upload protocol that I'm using latest resumable uploads](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-iOS/blob/master/YouTube%20Direct%20Lite%20for%20iOS/YouTubeUploadVideo.m).

If you don't want to implement yourself, you can use [ESSVideoShare](https://github.com/eternalstorms/ESSVideoShare-for-OS-X-Lion). (Will not work with iOS 7 or higher)

Comment: Thanks Ibrahim, but seems like your code also use the Google client library that I have mentioned in my question. I really need something very simple.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a project that handles for you. They implemented it for you basically.

Comment: Thanks again. Actually before you mentioned I have tried ESSVideShare. But it uses "ClientLogin" protocol and its deprecated. https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_clientlogin ( I got stuck at login and didn't bother to go any further. Didn't even mentioned because of that )

Comment: It would be nice if Google has release an iOS SDK as Facebook does for lazy developers like me.

Comment: Yeah whichever the way you choose, it will go through OAuth2 and upload protocol on YouTube, either you implement or use a module. I suggest you copy the protocol in direct lite or other example, so you have more control in future.

Answer (score 1):

The Google objective-c API client that you reference in your question has a sample app for YouTube authentication and file upload. You should be able to just copy and paste most of the code, just using the correct API keys that you obtained in the Google API Console.

Answer (score 0):

I recently discovered that the new 'Youtube Capture' app can be used with 
UIDocumentInteractionController

[Reference on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PreviewingandOpeningItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010410-SW1)

Sadly I have been trying to pass a caption using the annotation field without any success.
But if caption is not important, it's worth knowing.